# Fonts in IE look awful

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Fonts in the latest Chrome, Opera, Safari and Firefox look fine but in IE9 they look blurry and small in comparison. On other sites they look alright though?

Is there anything I can change in CSS to make them all look the same? Mainly the size as it makes the whole website look odd...

I'm using the following CSS:

```
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;   
font: 11px Verdana, Arial;
line-height: 13px;
```

Comment: What rendering mode? Do you have screenshots showing the problem?

Comment: Is Clear Type enabled on the Windows machine?  Are the IE zoom settings set to normal?  Also, what if you use 11pt instead of 11px?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the issue. The top 3 is Chrome, Firefox and Opera then the bottom one is IE9: http://i.imgur.com/JBfTt.png

Comment: Zoom is set to 100% (default) and it's a default install. I never use it for anything other than testing my sites.

Comment: Oh and it was originally 11pt but I changed to 11px to see if that helped. It didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

will make IE9 behave just that bit better.

Comment: See the comments I just added. I've already declared that. Any other advice?

Answer (score 0):

I would look in [HTML5 Boiler Template](http://html5boilerplate.com/). They've already solved all these little quirks and created a nice boilerplate for people to use.